# Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering

Tags: python, django

I have encountered an error:

> Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried my_view_two in module yourmodule.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'my_view_two'

The error is triggered from template tag:

```
<a href="{% url password_reset_link %}">{% trans "Lost your password?" %}</a>
```

Earlier I have `my_view_two` function and added that in urls.py too. But later I deleted the URL entry and function. But it is still giving an error.

Comment: can you show your urls.py please?

Comment: MatToufoutu, I have so many lists in urls.py, so I can not publish here. I have checked urls.py multiple times, there is no entry related my_view_two. Is there any way that Django create cache?

Comment: If the error is from that line in the template, what is password_reset_link set to in your urls.py ?

Comment: Maybe you need to clean *.pyc files?

Comment: Go into your ./manage.py shell and import the view - it will give you a more descriptive traceback. That might help you find the underlying problem.

Comment: then show us the method that password_reset_link is pointing to in the  urls.py

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar errors reporting on  `{% url password_reset_link %}` before - is that the first `{% url %}` in your template by any chance?

It looks as if that view is being imported somewhere (perhaps elsewhere from the urls.py?). Have you imported that view into another `views.py` file for example?). A quick way to find files containing this is to use grep (on Linux/Mac) at a command line in your site root:

```
$ grep -r "my_view_two" .
```

This will search for that string in all files of your project (if I've understood you correctly, it shouldn't be there).